# handleChange and onSubmit on javascript vanilla

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, form-submit

i'm working on my very first app : a login/register form with JS/node Js/ Mysql.
I'm trying to connect my form to my database (to collect my users' data into my db) but my code is not working. I didn't use "handleChange" or "onSubmit" functions because i don't use ReactJS framework. Do you guy think it's necessary?

```
this is my code : 

HTML code:
```

```
<div class="msg-alerte">message</div>
        <form method="post" action="http://localhost:8000/">
            <div class="formulaire">
                <h1 class="entete">inscription</h1>
                <input type="name" placeholder="nom" name="nom" id="nom" autocomplete="off" required>
                <input type="email" placeholder="email" name="email" id="email" autocomplete="off" required>
                <input type="password" placeholder="mot de passe" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off" required>
                <button class="btn-valider">s'inscrire</button>
                <a href="/connexion.html" class="lien-inscription">Vous avez déjà un compte? Se connecter</a>
            </div>
        </form>
```

```
JS (frontend) :
```

```
  const username = document.getElementById('name')|| null;
  const email = document.getElementById('email');
  const password = document.getElementById('password');
  const submitBtn = document.querySelector('.btn-valider');
  
  if(username === 0){

  }
  else{
    submitBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        //register-user??
        fetch('/', {
            method: "post",
            headers: new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'}),
            body: JSON.stringify({
                user_name: username,
                email: email,
                password: password
            })
        })
        console.log(username);
        console.log(email);
        console.log(password)

        .then(res =>res.json())
        
    })
  }
```

```
js server :
```

```
app.post("/",(req,resp)=>{
    //insertion d'une donnée
    const data={user_name:req.body.user_name,email:req.body.email, password:req.body.password};
    let sql="INSERT INTO users (user_name, email, password) VALUES (?,?, ?);";
 
    pool.query(sql,[data],(err,fields)=>{
        if(err)console.log("Echec d'enregistrement à BD");
        else{
            console.log("Enregistrement effectuee");
            resp.redirect("/");
        }
    });
});
```

```
THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP!!!
```

Comment: [Not working](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/) isn't a useful description of the problem.

Comment: lol... that's true... i get this message in my console log : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'then')
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (script.js:41:9)
(anonyme) @ script.js:41"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the main issue you will want to resolve before you can move forward is with your fetch call in your frontend code. You need to use the `then()` method on fetch so you can properly parse and read the response. Currently, you are calling `.then(res =>res.json())` on a `console.log()`. This is not valid.

I have made a modification to your event listener function that you can try

```
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {

    fetch('/', {
        method: "post",
        headers: new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/json'}),
        body: JSON.stringify({
            user_name: username,
            email: email,
            password: password
        })
    })
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => {
        // now we can read the response and decide what to do next
        console.log(data);
    });
})
```

I'm also seeing some possible syntactical issues in your node js code. Specifically with the request data assignment and the string interpolation on your query string. You could try something like this:

```
app.post("/", (req, resp) => {
    //insertion d'une donnée
    const data =[req.body.user_name, req.body.email, req.body.password];
    let sql="INSERT INTO users (user_name, email, password) VALUES ($1, $2, $3)";
 
    pool.query(sql, data, (err, fields) => {
        if (err) console.log("Echec d'enregistrement à BD");
        else {
            console.log("Enregistrement effectuee");
            resp.redirect("/");
        }
    });
});
```

Please comment if you need any further clarification.

Comment: Thank you @jiannone, i tried the modifications you suggested, there no error message in my console. but i still can't store users data in my database

Comment: @Anais for sure. I think then you have narrowed down any additional issues to your server code. See my edit for a suggested modification in your node js.